# Auto refresh (Ajax) not working

Tags: visualforce

This might be seem so simple,working on internal training and wrote this code which was not working (Quite embrassing!)

Can anyone point out where i was wrong.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opps">
   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:form id="theForm">
         <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
          <apex:outputLabel value="View:"></apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:selectList value="{!filterid}" size="1">
          <apex:actionSupport event="OnChange" reRender="list"/>
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
          </apex:selectList>
         </apex:panelGrid>
         <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:dataList value="{!opps}" var="opp" id="list">
         {!opp.name}
         </apex:dataList>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:form>
   </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: <apex:actionsupport/> event attribute value should be "onchange" instead of 'OnChange' silly mistake...

Comment: @SrvanAlaparthi Can you please create an answer and put your comment in it so that it is clear for others how your question was solved.  You can then accept it as answer 24 hours later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event attribute value should be "onchange" instead of 'OnChange' silly mistake... –